# From Discrete to Continuous Time

Tags: mathematical-economics

I know one form of a derivative, which is

$$ f'(x) = \lim_{\Delta\to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta) - f(x)}{\Delta}$$

Let $x_{t+\Delta} = x_t + \Delta \dot x_t$. [Achdou and coauthors](http://www.princeton.edu/~moll/HACT.pdf) (end of appendix A1) claim that

$$ \lim_{\Delta\to 0} \frac{f(x_{t+\Delta}) - f(x_t)}{\Delta} = \lim_{\Delta\to 0} \frac{f(x_t + \Delta \dot x_t) - f(x_t)}{\Delta} = f'(x_t)\dot x_t$$

I understand the first equality, that's merely the substitution. I can't wrap my head around the second one. How exactly does one show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\require{cancel}$$

Notice that if $\dot x_t \neq 0$, then $\Delta \dot x_t \to 0 \implies \Delta \to 0$

$$ \lim_{\Delta\to 0} \frac{f(x_{t+\Delta}) - f(x_t)}{\Delta} = \cancelto{f'(x_t)}{\lim_{\Delta \dot x\to 0} \frac{f(x_t + \Delta \dot x_t) - f(x_t)}{\Delta \dot x_t} \dot x_t}= f'(x_t)\dot x_t$$

If $\dot x_t = 0$, then $f(x_t)$ is a constant function.

Comment: Everything is now perfectly clear to me. I deleted now irrelevant comments of mine :)

Comment: So do I : ) ${}$